# details features about audio only transcodes for GA in google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-transcoder

My customer plans music streaming service, and wants to use Transcoder API to transcode music files.

Will Transcoder API support to transcode audio file to HLS/MPEG-DASH?

Their details requirements is following;

Input : WAV/PCM
Output : HLS or MPEG-DASH /CMAF
DRM : FairPlay Streaming, Widevine, PlayReady

Answer (score 0):

The team has audio only support on our roadmap. It's expected to be a post-GA feature. We have audio only support on the roadmap for Q4 2021.

Answer (score 0):

The required formats are supported by Transcoder API, I add a link from the public documentation with all the [Supported inputs and outputs](https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/concepts/overview#supported_inputs_outputs), also I add a link with the [Supported containers for content encryption](https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/concepts/overview#supported_containers_encryption), like FairPlay Streaming, Widevine, PlayReady