# How to make video or audio optional in transcoder api?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-transcoder

I am currently converting a video. Uploaded to cloud storage using a signed URL, using Transcoder API and transcoding a video larger than 5 seconds. But when video or audio is missing the job failed. How do I make video or audio optional for my job?

****My Current Code:****

```
job.config = transcoder_v1.types.JobConfig(
        elementary_streams=[
            transcoder_v1.types.ElementaryStream(
                key="video-stream0",
                video_stream=transcoder_v1.types.VideoStream(
                    h264=transcoder_v1.types.VideoStream.H264CodecSettings(
                        bitrate_bps=550000,
                        frame_rate=60,
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            transcoder_v1.types.ElementaryStream(
                key="video-stream1",
                video_stream=transcoder_v1.types.VideoStream(
                    h264=transcoder_v1.types.VideoStream.H264CodecSettings(
                        bitrate_bps=2500000,
                        frame_rate=60,
                    ),
                ),

            ),
            transcoder_v1.types.ElementaryStream(
                key="audio-stream0",
                audio_stream=transcoder_v1.types.AudioStream(
                    codec="aac", bitrate_bps=64000
                ),
            ),
        ],
        mux_streams=[
            transcoder_v1.types.MuxStream(
                key="sd",
                container="ts",
                elementary_streams=["video-stream0", "audio-stream0"],
            ),
            transcoder_v1.types.MuxStream(
                key="hd",
                container="ts",
                elementary_streams=["video-stream1", "audio-stream0"],
            ),
            
        ],
        manifests=[
            transcoder_v1.types.Manifest(
                type="HLS",
                mux_streams=["sd", "hd"],
            ),
        ],
    )
```

**Error message:**
No Audio:

> \atom atom0 does not have any inputs (input0) with an audio track

No Video:

> message": "editList does not have any input with a video track"

I have viewed the following documents.

- [How to make audio track optional for Google Transcoder API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69854394/how-to-make-audio-track-optional-for-google-transcoder-api)
- https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/troubleshooting#video-missing
- [details features about audio only transcodes for GA in google cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68897941/details-features-about-audio-only-transcodes-for-ga-in-google-cloud)

Comment: Hi @Mrcreamio, Currently it’s not possible to make video and audio track to be optional when transcoding using Transcoder API, this issue has been raised in this [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/238583496). However, we cannot provide an ETA at the moment but you can “STAR” the issue to receive automatic updates and give it traction by referring to this [link](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue).

Comment: yes. also on GitHub they have tagged this issue as a bug. https://github.com/googleapis/python-video-transcoder/issues/206